# Neovim does not self-report minor/patch version when built on Linux

Tags: neovim

I use two different methods to install and update neovim to the latest version (something that I do regularly these days): it depends on the operating system

- macOS: `brew upgrade neovim --fetch-HEAD`. It works well so far. I had some trouble earlier but `brew reinstall $(brew deps --include-build neovim)` fixed the luarocks error I was having.
- Linux: I run my `neovim/build-install.sh` script below:

`neovim/build-install.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Build the latest nvim downloaded from github. Instead of making a docker image dump the output in out/
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -o out .

# If nothing showed up (failed build?), abort. Heuristic here is to see if total dirsize greater than 20MB
if [ "$(du -s out | cut -f1)" -lt 20000 ]; then
    echo "Build output dir questionable, aborting"
    exit 1
fi

ls -la out
ls -la out/bin

# Install in to system at predefined location which matches the configuration made during build
sudo rm -rf /opt/neovim
sudo mkdir -p /opt/neovim
sudo mv out/* /opt/neovim

# install the symlink if necessary
if [ ! -f /usr/local/bin/nvim ]; then
    sudo ln -s /opt/neovim/bin/nvim /usr/local/bin/nvim
fi
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
from ubuntu:20.04 as builder

RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install ninja-build gettext libtool-bin cmake g++ pkg-config unzip curl git
RUN mkdir nvim
WORKDIR /nvim
RUN echo manual cache bust Sun 26 Mar 2023 11:29:55 PM EDT
RUN curl -L https://github.com/neovim/neovim/archive/refs/tags/nightly.tar.gz --output nvim-nightly.tar.gz && tar xf nvim-nightly.tar.gz && rm -rf nightly.tar.gz
WORKDIR /nvim/neovim-nightly

RUN make CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release CMAKE_EXTRA_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/neovim"
RUN make install -j32
RUN ls -laR /opt/neovim

# The export stage is used in this way to use this dockerfile to obtain a single built executable:
# DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -o out .
# ^ The above assumes this dockerfile is named Dockerfile in its own dir
FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=builder /opt/neovim/ .
```

In macOS, I see:

```
❯ v --version
NVIM v0.9.0-dev-1291+gbad218cd6-dirty
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/neovim/HEAD-bad218c/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

In Linux I see:

```
❯ v --version
NVIM v0.9.0-dev
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/neovim/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

And of course,

```
❯ alias v
v=nvim
```

Comment: currently i check `ls -la $(which nvim)` to get a sense of how out of date my nvim is on Linux but it's not ideal.

Comment: You can look at `brew cat neovim` to get a rough idea of how neovim is compiled by Homebrew; that might help adjust your script?

Comment: Thank you that is a very cool command to know about!